# Call a UITableViewFunction from another view

Tags: ios, swift, function, uitableview, core-data

I have a `function` called by a `UITableView` which updates a wallet value based on what it contains (hence the call by the tableView). This is part of the `WalletViewController` where the user can update what his wallet contains.

I would like to be able to call this function from the `MainViewController` where the wallet value is also displayed so it is up-to-date when the user refreshes the data, for now the wallet value update function is only happening when you load the `WalletViewController` and `reloadData()` is called.

What can I do to be able to refresh the value from the `MainViewController`?

**WalletViewController code for the value update function:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! WalletTableViewCell

    cell.delegate = self
    cell.amountTextField.delegate = self

    updateCellValueLabel(cell, atRow: indexPath.row)

    return cell
}

func updateCellValueLabel(_ walletTableViewCell: WalletTableViewCell, atRow row: Int) {

    //... calculations for each wallet's object are happening here ...

    CoreDataHandler.editObject(editObject: selectedAmount, amount: amount, amountValue: currentAmountValue) 
    // <--- calculations result for each object is saved to CoreData

    updateWalletValue()
    updateWalletLabel()
}

func updateWalletValue() {

    var items : [CryptosMO] = []

    if CoreDataHandler.fetchObject() != nil {
        items = CoreDataHandler.fetchObject()! 
    // <--- Calculations result are fetched from CoreData
    }

    total = items.reduce(0.0, { $0 + Double($1.amountValue)! } )
    // <--- Objects values are added together to get the wallet's grand total

    WalletTableViewController.staticTotal = total
}

func updateWalletLabel() {

    walletValueLabel.text = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: total))

}
```

**MainViewController wallet update function so far:**

```
func updateWalletLabel() {

    WalletTableViewController.init().updateWalletValue()

    walletValue.text = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: WalletTableViewController.staticTotal))

}
```

I guess I should get the wallet objects' amounts from core data and redo the calculations from the `MainViewController` to get up-to-date values? Or is there a more simple solution to call the entire `tableView` functions?

Comment: use post notification and addObserver in MainViewController.

Comment: Be aware that `WalletTableViewController()` creates a new instance of the controller which is **not** the instance in the storyboard. You need the actual reference to the controller.

Comment: @MRizwan33 how would that look like?

Comment: @PhillipMills I'm sorry but what do you mean? I know that's not what you mean but my core data functions are not in the view controllers.

Comment: @vadian Yes I know, which is why the values are not up to date I guess. What would you advise me to do?

Comment: If the `WalletTableViewController` is presented from `MainViewController` keep the reference of the former.

Comment: read answer carefully if u still have problem leave a commit.

Comment: How is `WalletTableViewController` presented? Is it instantiated and push onto the view stack from inside `MainViewController`, or is it pushed on via InterfaceBuilder-created segue?

Comment: @JordanBondo It is instantiated with `self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)` from `MainViewController`.

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple ways you could do this. @MRizwan33's answer will work if you want to go the 'post a notification' route.

The other option, which is what I usually do, is to get a reference to your `WalletViewController` from your `MainViewController` and then just make the call directly on the `WalletViewControllerInstance`:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    // Local variable to cache instance of WalletViewController
    var walletVC: WalletViewController?

    func functionWhereWalletViewControllerIsInstantiated() {
        // Save the reference to the WalletViewController instance
        walletVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(
                withIdentifier: "WalletViewControllerIdentifier") as!
                        WalletViewController
    }

    func someFuncWhereYouWantToUpdateWalletViewController() {
        // Call the function on your cached WalletViewController
        // instance that performs the refresh
        walletVC.doTheUpdate()
    } 
}
```

If you instantiate `walletVC` where you push it, you can do:

```
func functionWhereWalletVcIsPushed() {
    if (walletVC == null) {
        walletVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(
                withIdentifier: "WalletViewControllerIdentifier") as!
                        WalletViewController
    }
    // Push the view controller
}
```

You could also make the property lazy:

```
lazy var walletVC: WalletViewController = {
    return self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(
                    withIdentifier: "WalletViewControllerIdentifier") as!
                            WalletViewController
}
```

(I'm no Swift expert, so you'll want to double check the syntax)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can understand what you're doing here which is great! `doTheUpdate()` would then be an updated version of the `WalletViewController`'s `updateWalletValue()` where there would be `reloadData()` for the table too correct?

Comment: Sorry for the double post but I was calling `instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)` when pushing the view. When should I call it now? Thanks!

Comment: You can still do it there if you like. Easiest way would be to check `if (walletVC == null) { /* Instantiate */ }` before pushing it. Another option would be to make `walletVC` a lazy property so it is instantiated when it is first accessed.

Comment: Alright everything is setup, unfortunately calling `tableView.reloadData()` with `walletVC.doTheUpdate()` to get the latest data and update the wallet value makes the app crash with `Found nil` which makes sense as the `tableView` is not displayed. What can I do?

Comment: It seems as though you need to re-work how your update function in `WalletViewController` works. Obviously you can't call `reloadData()` on a nil TableView. What exactly is it that you're trying to display in 'MainViewController? If it's some value that's calculated in `WalletViewController` and saved elsewhere (CoreData?), you should consider moving that logic to another class & pass it from `MainViewController` to `WalletViewController` as a dependency.

Comment: Honestly it sounds like your original question has been answered and now we're moving on to a different issue. I'd be happy to continue this in chat if you like, but I don't think this is the place for that discussion any longer.

Comment: I think I might have wrongly thought I would be able to call `reloadData()` through the reference which took us all on the wrong path. I could call the fonction in the first place, but not with the correct (most up-to-date) values (obtained with `reloadData()`).  I think I need to build an independent fonction in `MainViewController` in order to be able to get the correct values and make the calculation, I am trying to display the current wallet value in `MainViewController`. Sorry about the misunderstanding. It would be great to continue in chat!

Answer (score 1):

Use this line from where you want to call for update another view.

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("NotificationIdentifier"), object: nil)
```

Add these lines in which update will happen:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector("Your Method Name Which you want to call on change like (reloadTableView)"), name: Notification.Name("NotificationIdentifier"), object: nil)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you point me to where to put them in my code? I guess `addObserver` goes somewhere in `WalletViewController` and `post` goes in `MainViewController`'s `updateWalletLabel()`?

Comment: addObsever will be in MainViewController and write method in selector 'updateWalletLabel()' and post will be in walletViewController from where the wallet value changes.